# Import excel sheet header in r

Tags: r, excel

I have a series of data sets stored in excel templates that i am combining using R. I have been using the XLConnect package to import the data, which works fine, however the template that was used to store the data has been through several revisions and the data i need to extract is in different places in different revisions.

Ideally I would get the revision number and from there i can tell r which cells / named regions to look at for the data. My problem is that this revision number is in the excel sheet header (i.e. the part only visible in page layout view). Is there any way of accessing this header from r, ideally using XLconnect as that's what i'm using for the rest of the import?

Thanks,

Graham

Comment: What do you mean by header? The header in excel is usually the first row, but you clearly mean something else.

Comment: By header i mean the part that would be printed at the top of every page were you to print the document, like the header and footer of a MS word document. In excel if you go to Page layout view (with the gaps between pages expanded) there is a part at the top that says click to add header. My revision number is in this section. Hope that clarifies for you @RHA